# How to display opened windows in task bar in xfce ubuntu desktop environment?

Tags: 18.04, xfce

I am using xfce ubuntu desktop environment, i want to be able to see which windows are opened currently in task bar just like windows desktop environment.

Is their any way to get it ?

Comment: any thoughts ??

Comment: there is a panel widget that does what you want, but I'm not currently using XFCE so I can't look what it's called. I have my primary panel (primary monitor) show only opened windows on that workspace, but the panel on my secondary monitor shows all windows (current workspace plus all others).  It's there if you look for it; but be patient if you want a XFCE/Xubuntu user to see & help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the Window Buttons plugin. Right-click the panel and select Panel > Add New Items, select the Window Buttons plugin and click on Add.

It will get added to the end of the panel.

To re-position it, right-click the panel, select Panel > Panel Preferences > Items tab, and use the arrow key buttons to move it around the panel to its desired location.